# Add a blank row to this access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to add a blank row to this query in order to show a subform. (if no data on the form, the form wont show. I need it to show so because it has calculated fields taken from the subforms not showing place holder may be "0")

```
SELECT Expense.Expense_Date, Expense.Expense_Type, Expense.Truck_Lic_No, Expense.Supplier, Expense.Invoice_No, Expense.Description, Expense.Amount[Driver Truck Link Query].TDesc
FROM [Driver Truck Link Query] LEFT JOIN Expense ON [Driver Truck Link Query].Truck_Lic_No = Expense.Truck_Lic_No
WHERE (((Expense.Expense_Date) Between Forms!EnterForm!Begin_Date And Forms!EnterForm!End_Date) And ((Expense.Truck_Lic_No)=Forms!EnterForm!T_Licence))
ORDER BY Expense.Expense_Type;
```

Comment: You can use `union all`, if you have to do it in the query.

Comment: Im not sure of the syntax, reason I'm asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select field1, field2, etc
from etc
union
select null field1, null field2, etc
from someSmallTable
```