# Add superficial record through query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to be able to on the fly create a placeholder record. So for example if I had *myTable* which had

```
-Apple 1
-Apple 2
-Apple 3
-Pear 1
-Pear 2
```

I need a query to be able to spit out.

```
-Apple 1
-Apple 2
-Apple 3
-Apple 0
-Pear 1
-Pear 2
-Pear 0
```

I would prefer not having to append actual blank records into the data, just have it appear in the query output. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the records?  And how will the "query output" be used / presented?  It matters, because there is no simple, built-in functionality to add records dynamically to standard query output.  It will most likely require "tricks" and/or workarounds that honestly may be more work than just creating a temporary table and inserting records.

Comment: Related question for [adding additional rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076780/add-a-blank-row-to-this-access-query), but it is prohibitive for many rows and does not support dynamic number of rows or data values.

Comment: You may be able to add records to a disconnected ADO recordset after first populating it from your table.  [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641760/ms-access-form-bound-to-ado-disconnected-recordset) with relevant code, event though the precise reason is different.

Comment: C Perkins, Gustav. The "Fake" record would not be used for editing, purely informational. I will be using the "0" value to key off a different joined table, and displayed in a non-editable form for the users.

Comment: That was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a `UNION` query that adds a `GROUP BY` query to the recordsource using a scalar 0. Below assumes table has *Fruit* and *Val* columns. However, `UNION` will order your *Val* columns as 0, 1, 2, 3... and `UNION ALL` will leave rows unordered with both zeros at the very bottom two rows.

```
SELECT t.Fruit, t.Val
FROM Fruits t

UNION

SELECT t.Fruit, 0
FROM Fruits t
GROUP BY t.Fruit
```

To place a row underneath the highest value of each group such as for *Apple* at 1, 2, 3,-->[4]<-- use a `Max(...) + 1` aggregate:

```
SELECT t.Fruit, t.Val
FROM Fruits t

UNION    

SELECT t.Fruit, Max(Val) + 1
FROM Fruits t
GROUP BY t.Fruit
```